# Create new folder on Gdrive using pydrive module

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

Trying to create folder on google drive using `pydrive`:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() 
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Authentication works, I can download some files from my drive, etc.

But can't figure out, how to create new folder. I'm trying:

```
folder_id = 'parent_folder_id'

file_metadata = {
  'name': 'test_folder',
  'parents': [folder_id],
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
}
file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
```

This gives error:  `'GoogleDrive' object has no attribute 'files'`

Seems i missing something from [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder), not sure what exactly though.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python sample code that is used in the [create folder example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#create_a_folder) uses [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/dyn/index.md) based on the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python), You can refer to this [Drive API documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/drive_v3.html) for the list of methods available in google-api-python-client.

pydrive has a different methods used for [Creating and updating file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#creating-and-updating-file). You need to use [CreateFile(metadata)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.drive.GoogleDrive.CreateFile) to create an instance of GoogleDriveFile then use [Upload()](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile.Upload)

**Sample Code:**

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() 
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
folder_id = 'parent_folder_id'

file_metadata = {
  'name': 'test_folder',
  'parents': [folder_id],
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
}

folder = drive.CreateFile(file_metadata)
folder.Upload()
```

**Additional Reference:**

[TO CREATE A NEW FOLDER IN GOOGLE DRIVE THROUGH PYTHON SCRIPT USING PYDRIVE MODULE](https://cppsecrets.com/users/155997114121971101219710097118575697110100495464103109971051084699111109/To-create-a-new-folder-in-Google-drive-through-python-script-using-Pydrive-Module.php)

Comment: This is outdated answer. Just produces "New Folder" in top level

Answer (score 7):

```
class Google_Drive:

    def __init__(self, folder_id):
        self.gauth = GoogleAuth()
        self.gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
        self.drive = GoogleDrive(self.gauth)
        self.folder_id = folder_id

    def create_folder(self, folderName):
        file_metadata = {
            'title': folderName,
            'parents': [{'id': self.folder_id}], #parent folder
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
        }

        folder = self.drive.CreateFile(file_metadata)
        folder.Upload()
```

Comment: This is correct answer